# Security Recommendation

Tags: linux, security

We have bunch of linux servers dedicated to do some tasks.

Periodically we need to run certain commands which requires root access.

So we have developed a web panel from which these administration can be done. Now the problem is we need to give the username/passwords to the developers of the web application, which we are not very comfortable with.

So we are seeking a solution such that the authentication will be done through a third party authentication scheme. So that we can control this third party. And the web application will be able to run commands on the server which needs root access.

We need a very simplified solution, not a full-fledged bloated stuff.

Comment: Why are you not comfortable handing out the passwords to this web portal when I assume you coded it in the first place? This whole question is very broard/unclear.

Comment: We do not want the developers of the web panel to log in the system. Besides, we feel that having "bare" password hard-coded in the source code is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but you can look into limited sudo access or a wrapper script to limit what their users can do.

Comment: I don't get it. Is the question what to do instead of hardcoding passwords in your app? If so, authenticate via PAM/a database/LDAP/...

Answer (score 4):

> We do not want the developers of the web panel to log in the system. Besides, we feel that having "bare" password hard-coded in the source code is not a good idea

You shouldn't be using 'bare' passwords - they should be encrypted.

The developers only need to have the encrypted passwords, so get them to provide you with a tool that will do just that. You then generate a password for $user run it through their tool and send them the username and the encrypted password.

The developers could trivially read the passwords if they are sent to the application unencrypted for comparison.

You should really have the client side do the encryption and send the result to the server for comparison and the whole thing should take place over an SSL secured connection.

Comment: Encryption is not the correct approach to use for storing passwords. Current best practice is to salt and hash the password. For transfer between client and server, encryption of the password using SSL is current best practice. The implication of that is, that the password will briefly exist as plaintext in memory on the server. Methods that avoid the password ever existing as plaintext in memory on the server exists, but I would not recommended using those until we have seen how they work out for early adopters.